# Returns NULL value

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate

I get the null value when i print the log for sourceDate.
it will give NULL value.

The code is:

```
NSMutableString * orignalStr = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[orignalStr appendString:date];
[orignalStr replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"T"
                            withString:@" "
                               options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
                                 range:NSMakeRange(0, 15)];
NSLog(@"The orignalString is =%@ ",orignalStr);

NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz "];

NSDate *sourceDate =[dateFormatter dateFromString:orignalStr];
NSLog(@"The sourceDate is =%@ ",sourceDate);
```

plz help me...

Comment: what does the log output for `originalString` ?

Comment: The Log should be like this..   2011-07-21 12:25:38.814 GameTimeBaseBall[1270:207] The orignalString is =2011-07-19 19 GMT:10:00 
2011-07-21 12:25:38.815 GameTimeBaseBall[1270:207] The dateFormatter is =<NSDateFormatter: 0x4e37ad0> 
2011-07-21 12:25:38.815 GameTimeBaseBall[1270:207] The sourceDate is =(null)

Answer (score 1):

Try using this date format string : `@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"`, without replacing occurences of `@"T"`.

**EDIT after comment**

You got a string like : "2011-07-19 GMT:10:00", the format string should be `@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd' GMT:'HH':'ss"`.

Comment: sorry, thought it would, I picked it from [Data Formatting Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1). What is the original string content (the `date` you appened) ?

Comment: you should escape static characters with ' as Vince mentioned: eg:`@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd' 'HH':'mm':'ss' zzz"`.  Your format seems to be wrong, you have the string `2011-07-19 19 GMT:10:00` and the format is expecting something like `2011-07-19 10:00:00 zzz`

Comment: I'm getting that(Date it is a string) from server side.

Comment: ok, but how does it look like (before replacing characters) ?

Comment: No not a change  again it give the string like 2011-07-19 19 GMT:10:00 before replacing characters...